# How to preprocess an image to remove noise and extract text Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

I have a really noisy image that I have to perform OCR on. The snippet attached is part of a bigger image. How would I go about pre-processing this image in the most optimal way?

I have already tried pre-processing the image using Otsu Binarization, smoothing the image using various filters and Erosion-Dilation. I've also used connectedComponentWithStats to remove the noise in the image. But none of this helps with the processing of the smudged text

Edit - This text needs to be pre-processed in order to perform OCR

```
img = cv2.imread(file,0)
gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)

_, blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(gaus, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
sizes = stats[1:, -1] 
img2 = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if sizes[i] >= 50:  
        img2[labels == i + 1] = 255

res = cv2.bitwise_not(img2)

(thresh, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|     cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

img_bin = 255-img_bin 

kernel_length = np.array(img).shape[1]//80
 
verticle_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_length))

hori_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

img_temp1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)
verticle_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp1, verticle_kernel, iterations=3)

img_temp2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, hori_kernel, iterations=3)
horizontal_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp2, hori_kernel, iterations=3)

alpha = 0.5
beta = 1.0 - alpha

img_final_bin = cv2.addWeighted(verticle_lines_img, alpha, horizontal_lines_img, beta, 0.0)

img_final_bin = cv2.erode(~img_final_bin, kernel, iterations=2)
(thresh, img_final_bin) = cv2.threshold(img_final_bin, 128,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Comment: post original image

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach to remove the noise

- Convert image to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
- Perform morphological transformations to smooth image
- Find contours and filter using contour area
- Invert image

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image

[image]

From here we create a kernel and perform morphological opening to smooth the image. You could try using different kernels sizes here to remove more noise but increasing the kernel size will also remove text detail

[image]

Next we find contours and filter using contour area with a maximum threshold area to remove the small particles. We fill in the contour to effectively remove the noise

[image]

Finally we invert the image to get our result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 150:
        cv2.drawContours(opening, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

result = 255 - opening 
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: But this does not still leave the text in a satisfactory state to be extracted. The text is still smudged and identification of the characters is difficult

Comment: For this case, it is difficult to enhance the text. Typical methods to preprocess text would be to use a sharpening filter or histogram equalization to enhance contrast. But in your case, the text is smudged so the best approach would be to use morphological operations. Another potential method would be to try skeletonize the image. You can do this with the [`imutils`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) library and the [`skeletonize()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py#L96) function